# Why does temporal workflow design numTaskqueueWritePartitions and numTaskqueueReadPartitions?

Tags: temporal-workflow

Can anyone explain why temporal need two paramters: numTaskqueueWritePartitions and numTaskqueueReadPartitions?

I think we use one parameters numTaskqueuePartitions for read and wirte which is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is needed to support shrinking the number of partitions without losing tasks. Set `numTaskqueueWritePartitions < numTaskqueueReadPartitions` to drain the backlog from the partitions to be removed. After no messages are left in those partitions set `numTaskqueueReadPartitions` to the value of `numTaskqueueWritePartitions`.